# About the latches generated by "case" syntax

Tags: mips, verilog, system-verilog

I understand when using case syntax in systemverilog, we need to fully describe all combinations or add a default to avoid latches.

Here is my example code, no latches are generated:

```
 module test(
input logic[2:0] op,
output logic a,b,c
);

    always_comb
    begin

    case(op)

     0: {a,b,c} = {1'b1,1'b1,1'b0};
     1: {a,b,c} = {1'b1,1'b0,1'b0};
     2: {a,b,c} = {1'b0,1'b1,1'b0};
     default: {a,b,c} = {1'b0,1'b0,1'b0};
     endcase
     end
     endmodule
```

As I said in the beginning, if add a default, not latches are generated.
Please look the second code, which is a ALU design:

```
module ALU(
output logic[31:0] Result,
output logic Zero, Overflow, Negative, Carryout,

input logic [5:0]ALUOp_i,
input logic [31:0] ALU_A_i, ALU_B_i,
input logic [4:0] Shamt
);

logic [31:0] adder_b;

always_comb
begin


  casez(ALUOp_i)

 /*Add_trap*/   0,1: {Carryout,Result} = {ALU_A_i[31],ALU_A_i} + {ALU_B_i[31],ALU_B_i};
 /*Add_notrap*/ 
 /*Subtrap*/    2,3: 
 /*Sub_notrap*/    begin
             adder_b = ALU_B_i ^ {32{1'b1}};
             {Carryout,Result} = {ALU_A_i[31],ALU_A_i} + {adder_b[31],adder_b} + 1;
           end

/*SLL*/         8: Result = ALU_B_i << Shamt;
/*SLLV*/        9: Result = ALU_B_i << ALU_A_i;
/*SRA*/         10: Result = ALU_B_i >>> Shamt;
/*SRAV*/        11: Result = ALU_B_i >>> ALU_A_i;
/*SRL*/         12: Result = ALU_B_i >> Shamt;
/*SRLV*/        13: Result = ALU_B_i >> ALU_A_i;
/*AND*/         14: Result = ALU_A_i && ALU_B_i;
/*OR*/          15: Result = ALU_A_i || ALU_B_i;
/*XOR*/         16: Result = ALU_A_i ^^ ALU_B_i;
                default:
          begin
               Result = 0;
               Carryout = 0;
               adder_b = 0;
          end        
  endcase
end
endmodule
```

The code above will generated latches, here is the result given by Quartus II:

> Warning (10240): Verilog HDL Always Construct warning at ALU.sv(16):
>   inferring latch(es) for variable "Carryout", which holds its previous
>   value in one or more paths through the always construct
>
> Warning (10240): Verilog HDL Always Construct warning at ALU.sv(16):
>   inferring latch(es) for variable "adder_b", which holds its previous
>   value in one or more paths through the always construct
>
> Error (10166): SystemVerilog RTL Coding error at ALU.sv(16):
>   always_comb construct does not infer purely combinational logic.

I did added a default in the end of the case, can some one explain what is going on? Many thanks.

Comment: One code suggestion: Why not do a subtraction instead of manually trying to negate `ALU_B_i`?  Your synthesis tool should be able to figure out how to do a subtract operation.

Comment: Yes, your correct. My first ALU design exercise used that code, and its worked fine, so I just copy and paste that code in every ALU I designed afterwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The clean and easy solution here is to assign a default value `Carryout` at the beginning of the `always_comb` block.  The last assignment will win, so any branch that does not assign a value to `Carryout` will get the default value.

A simple example of how the last assignment wins is shown below:

```
always_comb begin
   Carryout = 1'b0;
   if(some_condition) begin
      Carryout = 1'b1;
   end
end
```

In the above code `Carryout` is assigned to 0, and then if `some_condition` is true it is reassigned to 1.  If `some_condition` is false, then it just keeps the "default" value of 0.  This all happens in the same time step, so there is not transient glitch on the output.

Comment: what you mean by "last assignment will win" ?

Comment: Added a bit more to my answer to clarify.  I should also point out that I am aware that the code I wrote is a ridiculous way to do `assign Carrout = some_condition;` and is just meant to illustrate the concept.

Comment: So, with the default value we have in the very beginning, do we still need a "default" at the end of the case statement?

Comment: No, you could drop the default case and not get a latch inferred.

Answer (score 1):

While you are correct about multiple paths through a `case` statement (and needing a `default` clause), latches are also generated if a signal isn't present in every branch. In this case, `Carryout` and `adder_b` are only present in some of the paths. As a result, your synthesis tool assumes you want the values to be stored, which generates a latch.

You'll need to assign some value to those signals in every branch of the `case`. For example:

```
/*SLL*/         8: begin
                      Result = ALU_B_i << Shamt;
                      ader_b = 0;
                      Carryout = 0;
                end
```

Repeat for the other branches.

Comment: If I add the default values at the very beginning of always_comb, then no latches are generated. Is that also a solution for not give fully assignments in all different branches?

Comment: yes - in each path through the `always_comb`, each signal gets assigned a value. That method will also work.